# MasterPass Integration iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to integrate MasterPass sdk in iOS application. But I am unable to get any sdk for iOS. Has anyone integrated MasterPass SDK in iOS app?

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: have you done with masterPass Integration ,if so can you list down steps or procedure for this.

Comment: Have you done master Pass Integration, If then please list the steps down

Answer (score -1):

There is no iOS sdk for master pass integration in iOS . You need to use the browser integration for masterpass , or you can use the API's for native implementation .You can neither open UIWebview with the url for masterpass integration.